# Why is my Popup showing opposite the Placement property on some machines?

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a simple WPF Popup that I am showing when the user clicks a Button.

```
<Button
    x:Name="aButton"
    Content="Up/Down"
    Width="75"
    Height="30"
    Click="aButton_Click"
/>
<Popup
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=aButton}"
    Placement="Right"
    VerticalOffset="-31"
    StaysOpen="False"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="45" Height="45" Margin="2,0,2,2" Content="+"/>
        <Button Width="45" Height="45" Margin="2,0,2,0" Content="-"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

What is extremely weird ... is that this code works differently depending on what machine it runs on.

I run this code on my main desktop and everything works just fine ... and as it should. I run it on my PDC09 netbook ... and the Popup shows opposite (on the left instead of the right as I told it to with the Placement property).

Why is this? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I couldn't find anything via Google ... but a lucky search in the [WPF forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/threads), quickly found this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/19ef3d33-01e5-45c5-a845-d64f9231001c/). *Note to self: don't forget to search  the WPF forums if Google can't find anything.*

The answer is that my PDC09 netbook is a Tablet PC at heart, and apparently, Microsoft thought it was a good idea to show the Popup opposite to the Placement property on a Tablet PC that is configured for right-handed people ... such that the Popup doesn't appear under the user's hand.

The solution is to revert to custom Popup placement ... if you don't want this behavior.

I would love to hear about any other ways around this problem.

Comment: And btw, I always search SO to find what other people have found on the appropriate forums.  ;)

Comment: Glad to help you ... things like this, drive me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding a border in the same grid col/row as the desired placement target.  Then set this as the placement target instead.  By binding the width of this border to the popup content it will adjust it's width automatically therefore the alignment (left or right) is irrelevant.  If you want to still control alignment, you can do that by aligning the placement target border.
Hope that makes sense, if not, here is a quick example.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Popup x:Name="StartMenuPopup" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupTarget}" >
        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder">
        </Border>
    </Popup>

    <Border x:Name="PopupTarget" Grid.Row="1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=PopupBorder}" 
        BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <startmenu:TaskBar Grid.Row="1">
        <startmenu:TaskBar.StartButton>
            <startmenu:ToggleMenu Width="36" x:Name="StartButton"
                              ImageData="{Binding StartButtonImageData}"
                              AssociatedPopup="{Binding ElementName=StartMenuPopup}"
                              IsOpen="{Binding StartMenuOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </startmenu:TaskBar.StartButton>
    </startmenu:TaskBar>
</Grid>
```

The popup PlacementTarget binds to the PopupTarget border, and the PopupTarget border width binds back to the PopupBorder element.  This makes the PopupTarget border the same width as the popup therefore negating the alignment issue.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but would like to say this worked well as I've tested it on computers with both alignment types. I've added a margin to the `border` to get it to align properly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to employ a Markup extension. This extension dynamically adjusts the placement of the `Popup` based on the handedness of the device, determined by the `MenuDropAlignment` setting:

```cs
public class HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    static readonly PlacementMode PlacementOnRightSide;

    static HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension()
    {
        PlacementOnRightSide = SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment ? PlacementMode.Left : PlacementMode.Right;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return PlacementOnRightSide;
    }
}
```

It is then can be used in the `Popup` definition to provide the correct placement value:

```xml
...
 <Popup Placement="{Converters:HandednessToRightAlignmentValue}"
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=aButton}">
...
```

Please be aware that the `HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension` presumes that the handedness setting remains unchanged throughout the application's execution. However, should this not be the case, you can move the `PlacementOnRightSide` evaluation from the static constructor to the `ProvideValue` method.

Handedness of the device can be checked by `SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment`. In order to check the value of `MenuDropAlignment` in registry, run `Win + R` and execute `shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}`.